# Cloud9 IDE local themes

Tags: themes, cloud9-ide

The Cloud9 IDE docs say you can import a Textmate theme, but i cant figure it out. Can some one explain step-by-step how i can do this. Im trying to include the theme on my localhost by the way.

I found this link, but i still dont get it...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ace-discuss/kLgJFe2l2YY/47QvhIowqqMJ
.

The above url also mentioned being able to edit already existing themes. This would also come in handy if any one knows how to / where the files are located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps, assuming my theme name is 'pretty.tmTheme':

1. Copy pretty.tmTheme to 'cloud9/node_modules/ace/tool/tmThemes/'
2. Go to cloud9/node_modules/ace/tool/ and run 'node tmtheme.js'
3. Go to cloud9/
4. Run 'make ace'
5. Run 'make theme'
6. Open cloud9/plugins-client/ext.themes_default/themes_default.js and add your theme to the list. For ex: '"Pretty": "ace/theme/pretty"'
7. Run Cloud9 and select new theme from the view/themes list.
8. Enjoy! ;)

Comment: Sorry, i ended up giving up on this. I had found the files to the themes and was altering their styles, but for some reason i got no change. I then realized there were multiple areas throughout the code that had duplicate code for the styles. I think the farthest i got was changing the names of already existing themes from the drop down. But following that path the themes styles just wouldn't change... If you find a solution, please share. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it's strange that there's no easy way to do this. I've asked on C9 forum but no respose for now, when will help someone, i'll share solution here.

Comment: Also if anyone following these steps gets in trouble on step 2. Try running `npm install` while in the `/tool` directory.

Comment: I don't get it, where is 'cloud9/node_modules/ace/tool/' from where, terminal? I can't see that directory