# Cloud9 Custom Syntax Color Theme

Tags: syntax-highlighting, cloud9-ide, color-scheme, cloud9

Many are switching to Cloud9 IDE from other IDEs, and I did. But I miss syntax color schemes I had.

Luckily,  Cloud9 allows loading custom themes. https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/v0.1/docs/themes

Could someone create or share step by step, easy to follow instructions on how to import and activate a custom theme in c9?  Much appreciated.

Comment: This should work, but I don't get the first step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410610/cloud9-ide-local-themes  I don't get how to react 'cloud9' directory, from where